# Looking for RegEx to validate a string from input in an HTML form with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, forms

I need to validate a string from input in an HTML form with Javascript RegEx.

There may be an unlimited amount of "words" (any combination of letters and numbers - [a-zA-Z0-9], no symbols, underscores, dashes, hyphens) separated with a single space (" ", not mandatory after the last "word", or the first one, if there is only one). Minimal length of each of these "words" is 3 symbols, maximal is 10 symbols.

For example, string which could be valid - "bob BoB4U BOB4EVER 112233".

Presence any of the following "words" should make a string invalid: bo, b@b, bobobobobobobob, bob-4-u, b_o_b.

Have found RegEx for a length of the string:
^(?=[\S\s]{3,10}$)[\S\s]*, tried to play with it.

Also tried to combine the previous with something like ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,10}\s?)*$, but alas, didn't manage.

UPDATE. Strings and words given above are just an EXAMPLE. I do not need to filter out those particular words, it's just for a visual representation of valid and invalid items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a cleaner way to write it, but a basic example would be zero or more times match it with a space and at least one with the end of the string.

```
var re = /^([a-z0-9]{3,10}\s)*[a-z0-9]{3,10}$/i;
```

[Visualize it](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%28%5Ba-z0-9%5D%7B3%2C10%7D%5Cs%29*%5Ba-z0-9%5D%7B3%2C10%7D%24%2Fi)

Comment: Thank you! I tried almost the same and it didn't work. At first, I thought this one will not work either, but suddenly - it did.  Hope it will come with experience)))